# <div> layer stops the image slideshow

Tags: jquery

I have the following code it works alright but when the page loads, the image slideshow stops. If I remove the code the slideshow comes back up. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
<div id="darken" class="darkenB"></div>
<div id="popup_box">
    <div id="container">Airport Notam</div>
    <h1><div align="left"></div></h1>
    <a id="popupBoxClose">Close Notam</a>   
</div>
```

Styling:

```
<style type="text/css">

#popup_box {
    display:none; 
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute;   
    width:700px; 
    overflow:auto; 
    background:#FFFFFF;
    z-index: 100;
    border:5px solid #ff0000;      
    padding:15px;  
    font-size:8px;  
    border-radius:25px;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align:center;
}

a{ cursor: pointer; text-decoration:none; }

#popupBoxClose {
    font-size:10px;  
    line-height:15px;  
    right:20px;  
    bottom:5px;  
    position:absolute;  
    color:#ff0000;  
    font-weight:500;      
}

.darkenB {
    display:none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.7; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.70: /* FireFox */
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE */
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
    loadPopupBox();

    $('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {           
        unloadPopupBox();

    });

    $('#container').click( function() {
        unloadPopupBox();
    });

    function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
        $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
        $('#darken').fadeOut("slow");
        $('#container').css({ // this is just for style       
            "opacity": "0.3" 
        });
    }   

    function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
        $('#darken').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#popup_box').center();
        $('#container').css({ // this is just for style
            "opacity": "1" 
        });        
    }       
});

jQuery.fn.center = function () {

    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) +   $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}  

</script>
```

Comment: The whole codes from the page.

Comment: Take out "the whole codes from the page" and then put it back bit by bit, checking to see if it breaks the page.  You can then show us what piece of code is breaking it.

Comment: probably some js error is preventing things from working, did you check for js errors in the console?

Comment: If I take out a piece the whole code won't work!

Comment: You said the slideshow works if you take out the code.  So take it out and figure out which part is breaking it.  As above, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Archer, The code's working okay. It's just the slideshow that stops working. The page contains 2 parts 1. is layer.tpl and 2. is profile_main.tpl. Profile_main.tpl is rendered after the layer.tpl. Now the code that I have is in profile_main.tpl which is the rendered one, so I'm thinking that might be the problem? In the console there are lots of unknown and errors but none of them belongs to my code cause I didn't write codes for the whole page I'm just editing an existing page.

Comment: How can I load the page fully before the script? Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the page instead?  This sounds quite involved and may be too difficult to explain with just snippets of code.

Comment: @Archer, Yes but the page requires logging in and I don't think I should publish those information, would you give me your email address, so that I can send the info in private? Thanks :)